# prevent form to be submitted from the card reader

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form where required the user to swipe their card to the system. But, after the user swipe the card, the form will be submitted directly. It seems like in the card reader they have implemented the enter key after the card is swiped.

Anyone knows how to prevent the form to be submitted after the card is swiped? I need the user to fill in other information after swipping the card. At the end, if the user confirm, then they can just click on the submit button to submit the form.

this is the code that im trying:

```
<input type="text" name="hiddenkey" id="hiddenkey" onchange="return noenter(event)">
```

Javascript code:

```
function noenter(e) {
var key;      
if(window.event)
    key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
else
    key = e.which; //firefox      

    return (key != 13);
}
```

but the form is still been submitted as the 13 is for keyboard no. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should capture the `onkeydown` event and test for the `key = 13`

```
<input type="text" name="hiddenkey" id="hiddenkey" onkeydown="return noenter(event)">
```